# jQuery Change function doesnt work in some browser's Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".txt-qty").on('change',function(){
        var product_variant_id = this.id;
        var qty = $(this).prop('value');
        if(!isNaN(qty) == true) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?=base_url("/q/qty_data")?>",
                dataType: 'JSON',
                async: false,
                data: {
                    qty: qty,
                    product_id: product_variant_id,
                    payment_method_id : payment_method_id
                },
                success: function (res) {
                    if(res['message'] == 'reload'){
                        location.reload();
                    }

                    var product_variant_id = (res)["id"];
                    var price = (res)["price"];
                    var subtotal = (res)['subtotal'];
                    var total_price = (res)['total_price'];
                    $('#subtotal').html(subtotal);
                    $('#total_price').html(total_price);
                    $('#point_reward').html(res['point']);
                    if (product_variant_id == null) {
                        $(".cart-data-total").html(price);
                    } else {
                        $("#product_price_total_" + product_variant_id).html(price);
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }else{
            alert('Silahkan masukan angka quantity dengan benar');
        }
    });
});
```

this is my html form :

```
<div class="cart-data-qty pull-left col-md-1 col-xs-4">
    <input value="<?=$qty?>" class="form-control txt-qty" data-product-price="<?=$variant_discount_price?>" data-promo-id="<?=$product['promo_id']?>" data-product-variant-id="product_variant" id="<?=$row['product_id']?>" maxlength="2" type="text">
</div>
```

in case, that code above work find in mozila and google chrome in PC type, but it cant work in some browser on mobile such as : the original samsung internet browser, UCbrowser, but it can work in android chrome.

why it doesnt work? can someone tell me about this, and what should i do to fix this problem 
thank you (:

Comment: You could try targeting different events, such as `keyup`, since you are working with an `<input>` element

Answer (score 0):

you can try: `.on('keyup change'` or even `.on('keyup change drop paste'` instead of only `.on('change'` :)

That should work.

Good luck!